# where is the yellow warning icon in ie9

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-9, javascript-debugger

does anyone know how do we enable the yellow warning icon in ie 9?

I need to see the errors for a website (the website is deployed, and not on localhost)

Comment: You could just use Developer Tools: F12

Comment: @mc10 the f12 doesn't show me the error messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the gear at the top right and choose Internet Options, then go to the Advanced tab and uncheck the "Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)" option. After applying your settings it should now attempt to debug any errors it comes across.

Comment: i've tried that. it only works for "local" websites. but it stubbornly wouldn't show the errors for websites that are already on the web

Comment: @Joseph You'll need to go to a site that actually has errors (I did the same thing a moment ago wondering why I wasn't seeing any), for instance [Makezine](http://blog.makezine.com) has a few of them if you click on any of the articles.

Comment: i have a site that actually has errors http://qweop.com/testerror.html. but it doesn't show me the errors in the f12 console for IE (or i couldn't get it to)

Comment: @Joseph The errors would show up in a prompt (not the developer tools). It will prompt you and ask if you want to debug the error, in which case if you click yes it will then open the developer tools and take you straight to the error in the script. [Screenshot here](http://www.toastertreehouse.com/ie9debug.jpg)